# Image after Nav List that is using affix in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to affix an image to the bottom of a nav list and have it stay there when the page scrolls.

This is what I am wanting:

[image]

This is what I am getting when the affix kicks in:

[image]

I need it to stay just like picture one. I have tried googling the problem and searching stack overflow with no results.

Here is the code:

```
<!--SIDEBAR NAVIGATION -->
                <ul class="nav nav-list well hidden-phone hidden-tablet" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="850"> 
                    <li class="nav-header">The Green Panda</li>
                    <li class="divider"></li> 
                    <li><a href="#whatwedo">What We Do</a></li> 
                    <li class="divider"></li> 
                    <li><a href="#oursolutions">Our Solutions</a></li> 
                    <li class="divider"></li> 
                    <li><a href="#morethanwebdesign">More Than Web Design</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li> 
                    <li><a href="#contactinfo">Contacting Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="img/woody-effect.png" class="img-bottom nav-list" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="850">
```

Comment: Could we possibly get a jsFiddle to work with?

Comment: I'll try. give me a bit

Comment: I can't get a jsFiddle to work. the nav won't affix. Here is a link to the website: http://www.green-panda.com/website/panda/homepage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

The selector was incorrect.

If the height of your menu is static, you can add a class to that image when it switches over to the fixed styling and apply this css:

```
top: 310px;
```

That will position it at the bottom of your menu.

I would set up a class underneath .affix and have it applied to your image (add the id panda_logo)

```
#panda_logo.affix {
    top: 310px
}
```

Comment: Thank you the first time I did this I didn't set panda_logo as an id i was trying to do it as a class. Sorry about that. It works now thanks!